# Pop up a model to Display PDF document - Swift, IOS

Tags: ios, swift, popup

I have a Master - Detail application with Detail section filled with Table View. I know how to handle the row selection on a table view, but what i want is to pop up a model on the window and to populate it with a example PDF document i have in my project. I found [this](http://blog.typpz.com/2013/12/09/ios-sdk-create-a-pop-up-window/) example on how to create a model but two things, it's in objective C and it's limited to only displaying some static text. Can anyone give a good example link, that i can use to modify according to my needs.

Comment: Hi, I have created the popup you've posted. A swift version is available http://blog.typpz.com/2015/01/31/ios-sdk-pop-up-window-in-swift/ and the code is free on github for both swift and obj-c https://github.com/psy2k/NMPopUpView

Comment: @NikosM. Wow, that's Awesome. I was looking into the same example, but objective C, thank you :). One more question, do you know how to embed this on a row click inside Table View ?

Comment: In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method call this: `PopUpViewController *popViewController = [[PopUpViewController alloc] 
                                         initWithNibName:@"PopUpViewController" bundle:nil]; 
[popViewController setTitle:@"This is a popup view"];
[popViewController showInView:self.view 
                   withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"] 
                   withMessage:@"Your Message" animated:YES];`